# cakephp image link in action delete

Tags: cakephp, croogo

Im sorry  for bad english language :)

I want to display image in delete link, I have used this code but its not working

```
$actions= $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('/img/supp.png') . ' ' ,array('controller' => 'markets', 'action' => 'delete' , $market['Market']['id'], ), null,('Are you sure?'), array('escape' => false));
```

In action `edit` and `add`, below given code works fine:

```
$actions .= ' ' . $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('/img/edit.png') . ' ' ,array('controller' => 'markets', 'action' => 'edit', $market['Market']['id'], ), array('escape' => false));
```

I think the problem is in this : `, null,('Are you sure?')`

Comment: 1) please explain what "not working" means specifically.  2) don't start whining about no answer after only an hour - it won't help, and will more likely deter people from wanting to help you.

Comment: http://w3facility.org/question/implementing-a-clickable-image-for-delete-action-in-cakephp/ try this link

Comment: @Dave Im sorry for bad explication :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is wrong. Try the code fragment below.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
   $this->Html->image('/img/supp.png'),
   array('controller' => 'markets', 'action' => 'delete', $market['Market']['id']),
   array('confirm' => 'Are you sure you wish to delete this record?', 'escape' => false)
);
```

Comment: thanks @Franky but it's not working.  when click delete return url "http://localhost/bib/admin/markets/delete/4" and not delete

Comment: Thank you every body I find the answer correct  "$actions= $this->Form->postLink(
  $this->Html->image('/img/supp.png'), //le image
  array('action' => 'delete', $market['Market']['id']), //le url
  array('escape' => false), //le escape
  __('Are you sure?', $market['Market']['id']) //le confirm
);"